# Why number below maximum for float128 in numpy is treated as inf?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, precision

I'm using `numpy` under `python 2.7` and thought of using `np.float128` in order to represent a big number like 2e315. However it´s being treated as `inf` although it´s smaller than the maximum representation allowed which is near to 1e4932.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: np.finfo(np.float128)
Out[2]: finfo(resolution=1e-18, min=-1.18973149536e+4932, max=1.18973149536e+4932, dtype=float128)
In [3]: np.float128(2E315)
Out[3]: inf
```

The previous example was tested at [pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) with `python 2.7` and `numpy 1.8.1` which had following properties:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux harry-liveconsole4 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I also tested the above example under my local 64-bits machine but got error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'float128'` and I have `numpy 1.8.0` there.

What am I missing? What architecture should I have in order to have `np.float128` under python? 
Is there a workaround to represent such big numbers not as `inf` but to leave them as I input them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `2E315` get's evaluated *before* it is passed to `np.float128` and 2E315 evaluates to float('inf'):

```
>>> 2E315
inf
```

By then it is too late. Thankfully, the constructor accepts a string:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.float128('2e315')
2e+315
>>>
```

So, just to show you it works:

```
>>> x = np.float128('2e315')
>>> x
2e+315
>>> x // np.float128('1e312')
2000.0
```

This also works for me on Python 2:

```
>>> import sys, numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.11.3'
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=13, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> numpy.float128('2e315')
2e+315
>>> numpy.float128('2e315') / numpy.float128('1e312')
2000.0000000000000001
```

Comment: Are you testing this under `python 2.7`? Because I get different results. For `np.float128('2e315')` I am still getting `inf` as result.

Comment: Also my numpy version is `'1.8.1'`

Comment: @CedricZoppolo yes, this is working for me on Python2

Comment: @CedricZoppolo so, there are a lot of considerations. What is your system architecture, how did you obtain `numpy`? What operating system are you on?

Comment: I´m testing this under [https://www.pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com). And checked it´s still not working under `python 2.7` with `numpy 1.8.1`nor under `python 3.5` with `numpy 1.10.4`.

Comment: Architecture appears to be as follows: `19:11 ~ $ uname -a
Linux harry-liveconsole4 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @CedricZoppolo yes, well, there are *many possible reasons* why this won't work. Essentially, `numpy.float128` will be whatever the C- long double type is on your system. Try checking out what `np.longdouble` gives you. In any event, if you can't give more specifcs about the system, then there really isn't more I can say. You are using some cloud-based Python interpreter.

Comment: `np.longdouble` outputs `numpy.float128` under pythonanywhere. I also tried on my local machine and got error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'float128'` and I have `numpy 1.8.0` there. And my local machine is a 64bits machine under Windows 7.

Comment: @CedricZoppolo: Check `np.finfo(np.longdouble).max`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga On my local machine `np.finfo(np.longdouble).max` results in `1.#INF` and under pythonanywhere it shows `1.189731495357231765e+4932`

Comment: I finally tested this answer under a machine with following details `$ uname -a
Linux slackware 4.4.14 #2 SMP Fri Jun 24 13:38:27 CDT 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T2330  @ 1.60GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux` under `python 2.7` and got the expected results. Still would like to understand why the solution here provided doesn't work under the other situations detailed.